# How to stash changes in current folder?

Tags: git, git-stash

I would like to stash only the changes in the current folder and its subfolders.

How can I achieve that?

I have tried the obvious approach - `git stash .` but it doesn't seem to work.

I know I can create temporary commits and delete them afterward, but I want to know if `git stash` supports stashing specific folders.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @Shobit I get the help section for `git stash` command

Comment: You can't. `git stash` puts aside uncommitted changes in the working tree.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: you are correct in what plain `git stash` does. But using `git stash -k` and carefully preparing index it CAN be done - see my answer.

Comment: Not sure if it's worth the trouble though.

Comment: `git stash push -- path/to/folder` should probably be used - works for me. Please, accept the below answer by @gorpacrate.

Comment: @Danijel Done. thanks

Answer (score 223, accepted):

```
git stash push -- path/to/folder
```

Does the trick for me.

Comment: So to answer OP's question, `git stash push -- .` should do the trick ;)

Comment: older versions of git (eg 2.11) have `save` instead of `push`, and does stash all files, not just the specified directory :(

Comment: add `*` at the end to include all the files in the subfolders

Comment: @Rafa Right, the [documentation of `git stash`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) says: _`save` This option is deprecated in favour of `git stash push`. It differs from "stash push" in that it cannot take pathspec._

Answer (score 16):

`git stash` will not let you save partial directories with a single command, but there are some alternatives.

You can use `git stash -p` to select only the diffs that you want to stash.

If the output of `git stash -p` is huge and/or you want a scriptable solution, and it is acceptable to create temporary commits, you can create a commit with all the changes but those in the subdirectory, then stash away the changes, and rewind the commit. In code:

```
git add -u :/   # equivalent to (cd reporoot && git add -u) without changing $PWD
git reset HEAD .
git commit -m "tmp"
git stash       # this will stash only the files in the current dir
git reset HEAD~
```

Comment: Tried it, no way.. there's must be a better way

Comment: It prints the diff of all the changes in the project tree, and then I have to manually select which files reside in the specific folder I want. I don't even know the names of the files in that folder. that's not a viable solution to my problem

Comment: @Mellowcandle It is acceptable for you to create temporary commits to solve the problem?

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you:

```
cd <repo_root>
git add .         # add all changed files to index
cd my_folder
git reset .       # except for ones you want to stash
git stash -k      # stash only files not in index
git reset         # remove all changed files from index
```

Basically, it adds all changed files to index, except for folder (or files) you want to stash. Then you stash them using `-k` (`--keep-index`). And finally, you reset index back to where you started.

Comment: This will actually do something different: `git stash -k` will leave the index intact, so changes in the index will not be deleted, but the new stash will have **both** the changes from the index **and** those not in it, so it will be a "full" stash in any case.

Answer (score -13):

You could checkout one of the GUI git interfaces like SourceTree or TortoiseGit, things like this are what I personally go to tortoise for as it just ends up being much faster than trying to do many commandline commands.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Its a suggestion that doesn't solve his cli problem. :)

Comment: This is a comment not an answer